# How to get filenames with apostrophes accepted by PHP?

Tags: php, filenames, apostrophe

Barmar reckons this duplicates another question ... I'd already looked at that question and several others and I'm afraid they weren't close enough to my problem for me to spot the solution. Sorry to be dim at this, but I'm out of my field and need more precise help. So my question stands:

I am making a collection of pdf files available on a website, using a PHP script in their directory to read all the filenames and present them as links for downloading the files. However, some of the filenames have an apostrophe (eg: "Sean Ryan's polka"), and these will not open. An error indicates that the file "Sean Ryan" is not found - the script has called the filename only up to its apostrophe, so of course it doesn't match. All the ones without apostrophes work fine.

Several previous answers about apostrophes in PHP have suggested using htmlspecialchar, but I haven't been able to apply this successfully (I'm not a computing pro, just a musician wanting to make sheet music pdfs available to other players).  If htmlspecialchar is a solution, how/where would I apply it my script? Or is there perhaps another solution?

The server PHP version is 7.
Here is the script so far:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
function getFiles(){
    $files=array();
    if($dir=opendir('.')){
        while($file=readdir($dir)) {
            if($file!='.' && $file!='..'){
                $files[]=$file;
            }   
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }
    natsort($files); //sort
    return $files;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1><span style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-weight: bold; color: #0066ff;">The Rude Mechanicals tune library</span></h1>
<p><a href="../../index.html">Back to main website</a></p>
<h2><span style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-weight: bold;"> List of tunes (Category Scandinavian) </span></h2>
<ul class="dir">
    <? foreach (glob("*.pdf") as $file) 
        echo "<li name='$file'><a href='$file'>$file</a></li>";
    ?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Change quotes from `'` to `"` in your `echo`

Comment: @u_mulder That's only masking the problem, and would break filenames with `"` in them.

Comment: urlencode($file) ? I have had similar problem, and this is helped, but this is not the best solution ..

Comment: @Peter `htmlspecialchars($file)` is probably what they want.

Comment: Thanks @Peter ... yes I thought from answers to previous questions that this would do it, but I tried inserting it in several places without success. Where would I put in my script? And does it need any other symbols before and after?  Thanks.

Comment: Hm this is closed, but I think this is a real issue, and it have not answered on the 'original' flagged question :(

Comment: While not a solution to the problem you pose, using apostrophes and quote marks in filenames is reaaaaally asking for trouble. Rename the goddamned file, because even if your app doesn't break on this, some other will. Mishandling apostrophes in names is such a common and persistent problem/bug *everywhere* that you're better off not using them there, completely regardless of your app being able to handle them or not.

Comment: These are not filenames that I've created. They are the actual names of tunes, recognised by musicians round the world. It would seem very sloppy to list O'Carolan's Concerto as OCarolans Concerto, or Bess's Hornpipe as Besss Hornpipe.  But thanks anyway - maybe I'll have to resort to this.

Comment: @raysa Store a database of pretty names for file names. No reason you can't do `<a href="12345.mp3">A Beautiful Title for the Song</a>`.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz, but we're taking about a total of about 2,500 files. Bit more of a task than I'm looking for. I'm warming to the admittedly masking route of changing the echo line to double quotes (there aren't any of these in any of the titles) or maybe a line before the echo, changing the apostrophes to &rsquo;.

Comment: You really don't need to do that. Just change it to `<a href='" . htmlspecialchars($file) . "'>$file</a>` so the `'` characters don't break out of the `href=''` bit.

Comment: Thanks again @ceejayoz  I like this and will test it out in my set-up.